# How to serve .deb files compiled for amd64 without receiving errors that i386 .deb files are not available?

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, package-management

I have a repository on a ubuntu 12.04 server that is serving .deb files for only 64 bit architectures.

When I run `apt-get` update I get the following

```
W: Failed to fetch https://test.com/repo/dists/precise/Release Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

I'm using `reprepro` to add the `.deb` files to the repository

```
reprepro -Vb . includedeb precise package_amd64.deb
```

And in my distributions file `/var/www/site/repo/conf/distributions` I am only specifying amd64 bit architectures.

```
Origin: apt.site.com
Label: apt repository
Codename: precise
Architectures: amd64 source
Components: main
Description: debian package repo
SignWith: yes
Pull: precise
```

I circumvent the error by having my `sources.list` file include an entry that includes `[arch=amd64]`

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.site.com/repo precise main
```

However I would like to avoid having to specify that in my `sources.list` file.  Is there anything I can configure on the repository to tell clients trying to pull files from the repo that they should only expect .deb files compiled for amd64 architectures?

Comment: Any particular reason you can't compile it for i386?

Comment: I "can" compile it for i386 but we only need amd64 .deb files for use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On amd64 systems, apt tries to get both amd64 packages and i386 packages. This is (at least partially) because i386 packages are installable on amd64, and some applications and libraries are i386 only (Skype comes to mind). Therefore, apt has to get the list of i386 packages as well. Therefore, you get that error.

As for something on the server side, one way is edit the configuration file to allow i386 as well, and run `reprepro -Vb . export`. This will create an empty i386 Release and Packages file.

Comment: This will likely be an increasingly frequent issue for people, as for custom repositories there's hardly any point in building for `i386` any longer. In any case, though, the mentioned workaround of using `reprepro export` to create dummy files for `i386` indeed solves the problem.